# Passing a collection of item to search for in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a tab delimited text file I am importing its rows into a database but not all of its records, inserting only the rows that do not already exist in the database.
So I loop through the lines of this file, call my repository query something like this inside that for-each loop:

```
 while (streamreader.Peek() > 0)
 {
    string[] currentRowValues = streamreader.ReadLine().Split(delimiter);
    string lastName = currentRowValues[columnHeadertoLocationy["LName"]];
    string firstName = currentRowValues[columnHeadertoLocationy["FName"]];
    string middleName = currentRowValues[columnHeadertoLocationy["FName"]];
    if(!repo.IsProviderEligibleForImport(lastName, firstName, middleName)
    {
        // ok he does not already exist in DB, so go ahead and insert it, etc       
    }
// ....
}


    public bool IsProviderEligibleForImport(string lastName, string firstName, string midName)
    {
        var query = (from p in this.Context.Providers
            where
                p.FirstName == firstName &&
                p.LastName == lastName &&
                p.MidName== midName
            select p).FirstOrDefault();

        if (query == null)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

so something like:

```
foreach row in TextFile
  bool allowInsert = IsProviderEligibleForImport(pass params)
```

So the problem I see is that my test file has 108450 rows! So with this approach I will be hitting Database queries 108450 times which destroys the performance! I was wondering if there is some smarter way so I pass all of the records to search for in one pass and not one time for each row?

Comment: put your search criteria in a list and use the `Contains()` method

Comment: @SamIam can you please post an example so I can imagine how do you mean to do it, thanks.

Comment: can you please post an example of your loop that you call this from and surrounding code so I can imagine how your lines in your file are structured?

Comment: @SamIam Ok I updated my question with more surrounding code

Comment: How many rows are in the `Providers` table? Would it make sense to pre-load the table first, and query the `Context.Providers.Local` collection instead?

Comment: @RichardDeeming hmm, caching the whole Providers table? I should talk to our analyst about it but in my other similar project I think they said there are too many rows and don't do it but this one is a new database, might be able to cache it. I will check. Thanks

Comment: If you try to build one large query with LINQ, you'll probably hit the 2100 parameter per command limit. You might be able to use a stored procedure with a [Table Valued Parameter](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html) to query the data in one hit. Otherwise, you'd have to execute a query for every batch of ~700 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using SQL 2008 or higher, a stored procedure with [a Table Valued Parameter](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html) is probably going to be the best approach.

Depending on how complicated your "*insert it, etc.*" code is, you could either do the insert within the stored procedure, or you could return the new records to the code for processing.

**The table type:**

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.udt_ProviderImport AS TABLE 
(
    -- TODO: Match the data-types and lengths to your table:
    LastName    nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
    FirstName   nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
    MidName     nvarchar(100) NOT NULL
);
```

**The stored procedure:**
*Remove the `INSERT INTO (...)` block if you just want to return the new records to your code for further processing.*

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_ImportProviderIfEligible
(
    @data    dbo.udt_ProviderImport READONLY
)
As
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.Providers
    (
        LastName,
        FirstName,
        MidName
    )
    SELECT
        LastName,
        FirstName,
        MidName
    FROM
        @data As D
    WHERE
        Not Exists
        (
            SELECT 1
            FROM dbo.Providers As P
            WHERE P.LastName = D.LastName
            And P.FirstName = D.FirstName
            And P.MidName = D.MidName
        )
    ;
END
```

**The C# code:**

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("LastName", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("FirstName", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("MidName", typeof(string));

while (streamreader.Peek() > 0)
{
    string[] currentRowValues = streamreader.ReadLine().Split(delimiter);
    string lastName = currentRowValues[columnHeadertoLocationy["LName"]];
    string firstName = currentRowValues[columnHeadertoLocationy["FName"]];
    string middleName = currentRowValues[columnHeadertoLocationy["MName"]];
    dt.Rows.Add(lastName, firstName, middleName);
}

var data = new SqlParameter("data", SqlDbType.Structured);
data.TypeName = "dbo.udt_ProviderImport";
data.Value= dt;

// Use this if you're inserting directly from the stored procedure:
Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC dbo.usp_ImportProviderIfEligible @data", data);

// If you're returning the new records for further processing,
// create a type to hold the returned values, and use:
// var results = Context.Database.SqlQuery<ResultType>("EXEC dbo.usp_ImportProviderIfEligible @data", data);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this would work. Create a class or something to store your text file entries into:

```
public class TextEntry
{
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
    public string Middle {get; set;}
}
```

Then, I believe you can hit the database once with the 2nd line below. (With a large file, it might take a long time). Then you can filter based on the entries in memory.

```
var textList = new List<TextEntry>();

//load all the entries from the text file

var providersInDB = Context.Providers.Where(p => textList.Any(t => p.FirstName == t.FirstName && p.LastName == t.LastName && p.MidName == t.Middle));

var textEntriesNotInDB = textList.Where(t => !providersInDB.Any(p => p.FirstName == t.FirstName && p.LastName == t.LastName && p.MidName == t.Middle));
//add those text entries
```

To expand on this, you could also edit the `TextEntry` class to override the `Equals` method that accepts another `TextEntry` or a `Provider`, then you could use `Contains` instead of `Any` I believe.

Comment: From memory you'll get an error here saying that SQL doesn't understand the type `TextEntry`. This approach works perfectly if the list is of a type known to SQL - e.g. string, int, bool, etc.